# Need explanation on best practices for sharing data amongst multiple methods of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a file upload data processing app in rails. What is the best practice in making available the data to multiple controllers in rails? I have an action in my controller called `FileProcessing#upload`. This page (upload.html.erb) allows for the ability to upload and parses the csv file and stores into a nice old hash variable `@file_data`.

I have another method in my controller `FileProcessing#index`. This index method is there just to render the page `index.html.erb`. Now what? How can I show the data that was uploaded via the `upload` action in the `index` page? What is best practice for doing this? Could you explain some of the alternatives I have to be able to do this? I'm very new to ruby so a thorough explanation with my example would be amazing! Thank you in advance and sorry for the noob like questions. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that each each HTTP request will be routed to a precise `Controller#action`.
Rails will instantiate a new `Controller` object for each request, and will then destroy these instances as soon as the requests they are serving have been completed.

This means that two requests from the same client, even if concurrent or subsequent, will be be handled by two different instances of the `Controller`.

Also, if you decide to *halt* the execution of an `action` by calling `redirect_to another_path`, that will also be a different HTTP request, as rails will return the browser a [302](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) response with the new path as the destination of the redirection.

To answer your more practical question, you need to:

1. store somewhere the state of your application (the file, the date and time of the upload, the user who uploaded it, etc)
2. ensure that the `index` action has the means to retrieve that data.

On point 1, you can use the cookies, you can save that data in the DB and associate it to the user, etc.
On point 2, you can either retrieve that data using the user reference, or you can pass an explicit reference to the path helper, for example:

```
uploads_path
  # => /uploads

uploads_path(custom_parameter: "ninja-turtles", upload_id: 1337)
  # => /uploads?custom_parameter=ninja-turtles&upload_id=1337
```

done that, you'll have access to those parameters in the new action:

```
params[:upload_id]
  # => "1337"
```

Just be careful, because passing sensitive data as part of the URL string means that anyone can try to supply manually crafted parameters.

---

If you don't want to use different actions, on the other hand, you can just render the `index.html.erb` template at the end of the `POST upload` action.
In Rails, actions will default to render the templates of the same name, but of course you can customize that.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation. The only thing is, I want to be able to process the file on the fly. I don't want the database bottleneck because I don't care about all the data in the file. The data in the file will be computed and then the file will be deleted from the server and only the tabulated data will be associated with the user. Could I use ruby classes for this? Could you explain how regular ruby classes can be used here rather than a controller thats only good for routing. I don't want to go to the model layer for this because I just dont want to use DB for this.

Comment: That cannot be done. You'll need to **store** the data somewhere: DB, file system, Redis, etc. You **can** process the file and show some output in the same action, and keep all the data in-memory (as properties of a Ruby object), but then all the data will be lost after the rendering.

Comment: I just care about rendering the data to another page. Again, the data should not be stored. Can I share the variable that was populated in one action in the view of another action?

Comment: Yes. To put it simply, Rails will default to render the view with the same name of the current action, but you can override that. So, the action `ArticlesController#index` will default to the view file `app/views/articles/index.html.erb`, but you can specify another one. Whatever you decide to render, it will have access to all the `@variables` defined in the action.

Comment: You can specify another one with: `render 'articles/other_template'`. You need to specify a file without extension.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers and their actions "share" data in Rails by persisting it to some store (usually a database) and then making that data available via an instance variable `@variable_name` of the controller.

Likely, what you need to do is:

1. Upload your file to something like S3 via [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) or [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)
2. Store a reference to that file in your application database
3. Access that reference in your index action / view by pulling the ref from the db and putting into an instance var.

Comment: yea but I want to process the file on the fly. I don't want to load the data to a database, and then query it back out. I literally want to slice and dice the data on the fly from the file system and present it in the view.

Comment: You can still do that.  The above can be used to store the file to the local filesystem of the server as part of the upload operation (warning: this is not ideal in clustered environments or on hosting platforms like Heroku).  The #index action will still need some way to "find" this file though.  Could be a param in the URL, could be a database lookup, could be a session value - there's lots of options.